# How to fix "Invalid Cast" error when integrating SweetAlert with Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert

I have an Angular project where I've imported `swal` to it like so:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';
```

and I've used like this:

```
swal({
  text: "An Error Occurred",
  icon: "error"
})
```

The Angular app failed to compile and gives me this error:

```
Invalid cast. The supplied value [object Object] did not pass the test 'isJsonSourceFile'.
```

I've tried to install `@types/sweetalert` but nothing changed, I've tried to reference the script in the `angular.json` file .. same thing.
also I've tried to put `'sweetalert'` in the types array in `tsconfig.app.json` file`.. same problem.

Please note that:

1 - The moment I remove `import swal from 'sweetalert'` everything works fine as usual.

2 - The error is pointing to `node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js` file.

I have angular version 7.2.0, sweetalert version 2.1.2 and typescript version 3.2.2.

Also note that in typescript 3.1 the code i've wrote will work fine, and this error won't show up.

Any Suggestions to make it works with typescript 3.2 ? and Thanks.

Comment: It works out of box , demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zphi8m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @ABOS that's right. so why it isn't working in my case. I can supply more specific information about my project if it helps detecting the problem.

Comment: @ABOS I don't know, its not something I've implemented.. please note that the moment I remove the `import swal from 'sweetalert'` everything works fine as usual.

Comment: looks like typescript issue ...

Comment: @ABOS yes it is, the error is pointing to `node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js` file.

Comment: what is your typescript version?

Comment: @ABOS I have `typescript 3.2.2`, `ts-node 7.0.0` and `tslint 5.11.0`.

Comment: not sure what is happening... perhaps you can follow https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28762

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @ABOS turns out downgrading typescript to 3.1 solves the problem as it mentioned in the link you're provided, but its a little bit weird since it worked it your example

Comment: hmm, odd. anyway, it works automagically after downgrading :)